# Injectable async custom route decorator in NestJS as an alternative to expressjs app.param

Tags: nestjs

There is a need to load objects to the request according to the route param like it is in
[express app.param](https://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#app.param).
I am implementing it by a route custom parameter. And I am wondering.
Is it possible to implement a custom async injectable router parameter decorator?
There is a section in the documentation on how to create a custom route decorator and it
does not show these abilities on [Custom decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)
Advise me on some good practices.
Regards.